# Symfony - image does not show up on page

Tags: php, image, symfony, url-routing, assets

I am fairly a beginner at Symfony, doing rather well, but still having problem with images on page. These are facts:

- application is local, web page does not go live
- application is set in Apache so that start page is called using only a name:

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/HealthCareSymfony/web/app_dev.php"
      ServerName HealthCareSymfony
   </VirtualHost>
  ```
- application start page is therefor just "http://healthcaresymfony/"
- images are copied in web/images folder (though I tried othe folders too, like Resources/public/images etc)
- standard image asset in twig:

  ```
  img src="{{ asset('/images/Poppy-3.png') }}" alt="beach"
  ```
- tried the previous with number of other versions of path... none worked!
- when I try to get page with image like  (got the path from inspect page) "http://healthcaresymfony/web/images/Poppy-3.png" I get error "No route found for "GET /web/images/Poppy-3.png"
- tried number of ways to get page with this image, always same error.

Please, help me to find what am I doing wrong here!

Answer (score 2):

I would say your DocumentRoot was incorrectly set

It should not point to the actual `app_dev.php` script

instead use

```
DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/HealthCareSymfony/web
```

Also your image does not seem to have `<` and `>` even when using twig the HTML you use should be correctly formed

```
<img src="{{ asset('/images/Poppy-3.png') }}" alt="beach">
```

Here is an example of one of my Symfony project Virtual Hosts

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sitename.test
    ServerAlias www.sitename.test
    DocumentRoot c:/websrc/sitename/web
    <Directory  "c:/websrc/sitename/web/">

        AllowOverride All
        Require local

        # this forces app_dev.php to be run by default
        <IfModule rewrite_module>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You would also have to add `sitename.test` into your HOSTS file to make this work

```
127.0.0.1 sitename.test
::1 sitename.test
```

Then restart the `dnscache` from a command windows started using "Start as Administrator"

```
>net stop dnscahce
>net start dnscache
```

or reboot the PC

Comment: Thank you but it did not work. When remove app_dev.php from DocumentRoot and directory in VirtualHost, I get pages from some couple of months old versions of program, possibly the first version. I am not sure how that's possible but it happens.